# How to add row(data) to the existing Google SpreadSheet from HTML using javascript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a input text box for capturing email address.After submit, I want to add the email address to the existing Google spreadsheet in the back end in HTML.Can any one please help me.Thank's in advance.

Code
html:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="field_content">
        <input class="field" type="text" id="email_id"  />
        <input class="submit" type="button" onclick="addEmail()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

    function addEmail(){
        var email_id = $('#email_id').val();
        if ((email_id != "") && (validateEmail(email_id))){
            alert("valid");
            //Here i want to save in Google Spreadsheet
        }
        else {
            if(email_id == ""){
                alert('Please enter Email ID');
                return false;
            }
            alert('INvalid Email ID');
        }
        $('#email_id').val('');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What back end technology is being used. Post the code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Apps Script, you must use:

```
google.script.run.gsFunctionNameInAppsScript()
```

[Google Documentation - Client Side API - Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

If you are not using Apps Script, you must use a different API specific to the server side language.

```
<script>
  function onSuccess(argReturnValue) {
    if (argReturnValue === true) {
      alert('The email was saved to the spreadsheet!');
    };
  };

  function addEmail(){
    . . . . Your existing code . . . 
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .addRowToSpreadsheet(email_id);
</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function addRowToSpreadsheet(argTheEmail) {
  var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = thisSS.getSheetByName("Email_List");
  theSheet.appendRow([argTheEmail]);
  return true;
}
```